# Spring Boot java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/utils/logging/MessageBuilder

Tags: java

I'm studying SpringBoot with helloworld application, but encountered an issue after clicking Maven package with below errors, and tried to find the answer a couple of hours, but still cannot fix it. Could you help me out. Thanks.

Here is the source code download link: [download here](http://150.158.125.28:9000/doc/springhelloworld.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=admin%2F20201128%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201128T140324Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=6ec202a8d980196e2627942b860da9920f10237bb50e0d2c76f2f452bcd1deeb)

```
[INFO] ---------------< org.example:spring-boot-01-helloworld >----------------
[INFO] Building spring-boot-01-helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ spring-boot-01-helloworld ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ spring-boot-01-helloworld ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo
   *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/shared/utils/logging/MessageBuilder*
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Unknown Source)
```

Comment: here is the source code for the simple helloworld project,could you help check and make it workable. I would much appreciate.

Comment: here is the source code download link: http://150.158.125.28:9000/doc/springhelloworld.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=admin%2F20201128%2F%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201128T140324Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=6ec202a8d980196e2627942b860da9920f10237bb50e0d2c76f2f452bcd1deeb